# How to handle Javascript callbacks in cordova iOS plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, native, cordova-plugins

So I have a cordova iOS plugin that spawns a uiView

[self.pluginviewContoller presentViewController:self.myView animated:YES completion:nil];

Now in the view controller I want to do callbacks to my javascript code on specific events. I have tried instantiating the class that inherits CDVPlugin but it does not work.

How do I go about doing this in the right way?

Comment: You have to provide more information if you want somebody to help you. self.myView is a UIViewController or a UIView? have you heard of delegates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this on events:

```
NSDictionary *payload = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    messageParameter1, @"message1", 
    messageParameter2, @"message2", 
    nil];

CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsDictionary:payload];
[pluginResult setKeepCallbackAsBool:YES];

[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
```

`[pluginResult setKeepCallbackAsBool:YES];` is the key, as if you do not add that, the callback is finalized and will accept no further events.